# GoogleML training speed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow

I am training a neural network with tensorflow and I save my data in a persistent disk in Google Cloud.

I have seen that Google offers a training service as part of GoogleML.
They ask to store the data in a bucket.

As far as I know, reading/writing ops are slower from the bucket storage compared to a persistent disk. 
So - what does it mean on the service? Is it so slower because of the storage of the data? How can I fix it? Someone knows what is the speed difference?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a "persistent disk". Buckets are indeed persistent disks. If they are in the same data-center/region as your GoogleML tasks, the access speed will be similar. Also, you should make sure that while training most data is fed constantly to the trainer from the RAM so it doesn't have to actually access the disk at each training step.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used this link of Google:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/

Maybe I've got it wrong - but it seemd here that the bucket storage is slower...  What am I missing?

Comment: In most cases the bottleneck is not the disk, but the GPU. If the disk speed access is the bottleneck then you should first load the data in memory (RAM) and serve it from there to your GPU.

Comment: I agree. But what will you do if the whole dataset doesn't fit into my RAM size?

Comment: You don't need the entire dataset at once. You could keep reading training samples from the disk into a RAM buffer and then send them from RAM to your GPU/tensorflow. The thing is that not reading the samples is the bottleneck, but running your neural net training algorithm, so it's unlikely you will have to wait for the disk.

Comment: I understand. Thank you